# What is a Flash drive by download?

Tags: virus, flash

I've seen many people saying how some sites can infect your computer without actually clicking anything. They said that it was a "Flash Drive By" and it would use flash to download a file of any kind. Does that really exist or could it be something else?

Answer (score 10):

It's not called Flash Drive By, but Drive-By Download, and yes, it's basically downloading malware just by visiting an infected website. Usually drive-by downloads work by exploiting a browser vulnerability (or a vulnerability in plugin like Flash or Adobe Reader), which leads to remote code execution triggering the download of malware.

Unfortunately drive-by downloads are getting more and more popular, especially that many legitimate websites get infected by adding a malicious Javascript code to their pages. That in turn usually happens with SQL injection and/or XSS. So, basically, a web application vulnerability in a legitimate website may lead to system-level exploitation of clients that visit it.

You can learn more about Drive-By-Downloads, the mechanism of infections, the statistics etc. in the following [OWASP presentation](https://www.owasp.org/images/e/ec/OWASP_Dasient_11_10_10.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it exists. There have been a lot of vulnerabilities in Flash that allow code execution if the user views a flash file (which most browsers will do automatically, if you have the plugin installed).